# Xtext 2.9 formatting enums

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, xtext

I have a DSL powered by Xtext and I am currently setting up the formatter under the new Formatter 2.9 API. It worked great so far but I tried to make it exhaustive (so all whitespace is formatted) but I can't format my RelationalOperators as they are defined as an enum:

```
enum RelationalOperator:
   EQUALS='=' | LESS='<' | GREATER='>' | LESS_EQUAL='<=' | GREATER_EQUAL='>=' | UNEQUAL='!='
;
```

The usual approach is that for each eObject in the AST a method is called.
The problem is that for an enum there isn't such an object and I don't want to define the formatting in every object that uses a relational operator. Also formatting them as keywords does not work.

I can however access the 'EnumRule' but I have no clue how I can get from there to a text region.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to configure formatting for the whitespace that is *contained* by an object, but not for the whitespace *surrounding* that object. This helps to avoid conflicts with formatting specifications.

For enums this means there is nothing to do, since an enum literal does not contain any whitespace. You have to format the RelationalOperator wherever it is used in your meta model, e.g. put `oneSpace` before and after the operator. You might be able to extract this to a separate method in order to reuse some formatting code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in my case that would be a really bad practice. The grammar I am working with contains multiple specification languages which all use relational operators and I always want to treat the operators the same e.g. surround them by single spaces. So following your approach would cause massive repetition and is harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super hacky workaround written in Xtend that formats every single semantic region in the document if it has the same text as the enum-element. Superlow priority so it does not conflict with any other formatting.

```
protected def formatRelationalOperators(XtextRoot root, extension IFormattableDocument document) {
    val relationalOperatorLiterals = RelationalOperator.values.map[literal]
    val regions = root.allSemanticRegions.filter[relationalOperatorLiterals.contains(text)]
    val superLow = IHiddenRegionFormatter.LOW_PRIORITY - 1
    regions.forEach[surround[oneSpace; priority = superLow]]
}
```

XtextRoot is just the root entity of the AST.